# Laravel Breeze with vue 3 Update image but return null

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite, breeze, inertiajs

im trying to update image files to database,forms sends null value but it shouldnt, it works fine when changing text, the problem occurs when changing image.

!!!!here is the controller update!!!!

```
use App\Models\kontraktor;
use App\Http\Requests\StoreImage;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Inertia\Inertia;
use Inertia\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Auth;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

public function update(Request $request, kontraktor $kontraktor): RedirectResponse
    {
         $this->authorize('update', $kontraktor);
        
         if ($request->hasFile('foto_kontraktor')) {
             Storage::disk('public')->delete($request->foto_kontraktor);
 
             $filePath = Storage::disk('public')->put('foto_kontraktor', request()->file('foto_kontraktor'), 'public');
             $request->foto_kontraktor = $filePath;
         }
 
         $kontraktor->update($request->all());
 
 
        return redirect(route('kontraktor.index'));
    }
```

!!!!and here is the vue 3 template with its script!!!!

```
<script setup>
import { useForm } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import { ref } from 'vue';
import Dropdown from '@/Components/Dropdown.vue';
import InputError from '@/Components/InputError.vue';
import PrimaryButton from '@/Components/PrimaryButton.vue';
import DropdownLink from '@/Components/DropdownLink.vue';
import { Link } from '@inertiajs/vue3';

const props = defineProps(['data']);
     const form = useForm({
     foto_kontraktor: props.foto_kontraktor,
     nama_kontraktor: props.data.nama_kontraktor,
     proyek_aktif_kontraktor: props.data.proyek_aktif_kontraktor,
     histori_proyek_kontraktor: props.data.histori_proyek_kontraktor,
 });
 
const edit = ref(false);
const previewImage = ref(null);

const handleFileChange = (event) => {
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  const reader = new FileReader()
  reader.onload = () => {
    previewImage.value = reader.result
    
  }
  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
  }
</script>
<template>=
            <form @submit.prevent="form.put(route('kontraktor.update', data.id), { onSuccess: () => edit = false })">
                <label>Foto Kontraktor</label><br>
                <img v-if="!previewImage" :src="'storage/'+data.foto_kontraktor" alt="preview">
                <img v-if="previewImage" :src="previewImage" alt="preview">
                <input type="file" @change="handleFileChange"  @input="form.foto_kontraktor = $event.target.files[0]" accept="image/*"/>
                <br>
                <label>Nama Kontraktor</label>
                <input
                    v-model="form.nama_kontraktor"
                    placeholder="Nama Kontraktor"
                    class="block w-full border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-md shadow-sm"
                    style="padding: 5px;border: 1px solid grey;"
                    required
                >
                <br>
                <div>
                    <label>Proyek Aktif </label>
                <textarea
                    v-model="form.proyek_aktif_kontraktor"
                    placeholder="Proyek Aktif Kontraktor"
                    class="block w-full border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-md shadow-sm"
                    style="padding: 5px;border: 1px solid grey; "
                ></textarea>
                </div>
                <br>
                <label>History Proyek</label>
                <textarea
                    v-model="form.histori_proyek_kontraktor"
                    placeholder="History Proyek Kontraktor"
                    class="block w-full border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-md shadow-sm"
                    style="padding: 5px;border: 1px solid grey;"
                ></textarea>
                <div class="space-x-2">
    <PrimaryButton class="mt-4">Save</PrimaryButton>
    <button class="mt-4" @click="edit = false; form.reset(); form.clearErrors()">Cancel</button>
</div>
            </form>
</template>
```

i hope somebody knows where the problem is, im new to laravel please help me